# How raising or lowering access modifier in derived class destroys C++ encapsulation?

Tags: c++

While learning C++ from **The Complete Reference** in the topic of **Granting Access** of **Inheritance** it is written that we can restore members of a class to their original access state.

**Example**

```
class Base {
public:
    int x;
};

class Derived : private Base {
public:
    Base::x; // make x public again
};
```

According to author

> You can use an access declaration to restore the access rights of public and
>   protected member.
>   However,you can not use an access declaration to  raise or lower the access status of a member.
>   For example a member declared as private in base class can't be made public by derived class.
>   If C++ allows this to occur , it would destroy its encapsulation mechanism.

I am not understanding how will it happen?

Comment: You need to quote the full context. `We can not raise or lower the access status of a member` This is not correct in general. For example, a class using protected or public inheritance *can* expose a protected member of the base class as public.

Comment: I added the full paragraph @dxiv

Comment: `x` is already public in `Base`... Also are you missing `using`?

Comment: @newbee Are you sure that's the full paragraph, literally? `You can use an access declaration to restore the access rights of public and protected member. However,you can not use an access declaration to raise or lower the access status of a member.` The 2nd sentence contradicts the 1st one unless you change `member` to `private member`.

Comment: Which edition are you using? This looks like pre-standard C++.

Comment: Yes Sir! This is the full paragraph. @dxiv

Comment: fourth edition. @n.m.

Comment: This is unfortunate. Access declarations are deprecated and the book shouldn't have talked about them at all except maybe in a footnote. Consider getting another book.

Comment: @n.m. Good point. They are deprecated in favour of "using declaration" (only if required. In the above case, of inheritance, it is not required. It only confuses things).

Answer (score 0):

It is talking about [using declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration).

By making use of "using declaration" you can bring names into current scope, so that they become visible to your current block of code, so that they become readily resolvable, so that you can reduce ambiguity during multiple inheritance, so that you don't have to type long specifiers in order to access them (like the short-cut of using *cout* instead of *std::cout*.) But, their access status still remains same (private remains private, public remains public, protected remains protected).

```
class Base {
    public:
    int x;
    private:
    int y;
    protected:
    int z;
};

class Derived : public Base {

    // Bring x,y,z into scope
    // x is still public. y is still private. z is still protected.

    using Base::x;
    using Base::y; // This fails to compile. Why bring something into scope when you don't have access to it?
    using Base::z;
};
```

The above code isn't a convincing example of *using declaration* (because, inheritance already brings names into scope). It becomes more useful in other cases (like multiple inheritance or when you are trying bring a name that is very distance away from your current scope (like creating a short-cut name).

```
namespace X {
    namespace Y {
       namespace Z {
          namexpace W {
              int deep_x;
              int deep_y;
          }
       }
    }
 }

int main()
{
     cout << X::Y::Z::W::deep_x;
     // Bringing X::Y::Z::W::deep_y into scope
     using X::Y::Z::W::deep_y;
     cout << deep_y;
}
```